# "your system is running in low graphics mode issue"

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics

i dual booted my windows 8 pc with ubuntu 13.10. when i select ubuntu from boot menu then i got an error message saying that "your system is running in low graphics mode".i am using hp pavilion 15-n0t0tx (graphics processor radeon hd 8670m). what is to do?
someone says that reinstall your graphics driver using command prompt but i don't know how to dawnload things from command prompt.i am new at linux. please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 0):

First install latest kernel http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-19-rc4-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivatives/

reboot system and check if it works,if it doesnt execute

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and modify this line

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

to look exactly like this.

execute

> sudo update-grub
>   sudo update-grub2

reboot and check if it works.